# Unable to determine the principal end of an association , One to One relation of SQL

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc

This is my error :
Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'SANTEK.Web.Models.SantekOrder' and 'SANTEK.Web.Models.OrderMoneySum'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.

What is my mistake logically ?? I mean to build one-to-one relation.

My model classes are here :

```
       [Table("Orders")]
public class SantekOrder
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int SantekOrderId { get; set; }
    [Required, StringLength(25)]
    [DisplayName("Çatdırılacaq şəxs")]
    public string DelivaryManName { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Çatdırılacaq şəxs istifadəçidir?")]
    public bool DeliveryManIsUser { get; set; }
    [Required, StringLength(25)]
    [DisplayName("Çatdırılacaq şəxs ad və soyadı")]
    public string DelivaryManSurname { get; set; }
    [Required, StringLength(10)]
    [DisplayName("Çatdırılacaq şəxs tefon nömrəsi")]
    public string DelivaryManTel { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Çatdırılacaq ünvan istifadəçinin ünvandır?")]
    public bool IsUserAddress { get; set; }
    [Required, StringLength(150)]
    [DisplayName("Çatdırılacaq şəxsin ünvanı?")]
    public string DelivaryManAddress { get; set; }
    public int SanTekUserId  { get; set; }
    public int OrderMoneySumId { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy-hh-mm-ss}", 
    ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SanTekUserId")]
    public virtual SanTekUser SanUser { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SanTekUserId")]
    public virtual OrderMoneySum OrderMoneySum { get; set; }

}
```

This is my OrdersDetail Table to hold all product and their quantity

```
     [Table("OrderedProducts")]
     public class OrderMoneySum
    {
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int OrderMoneySumId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int SantekOrderId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int AllProductId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Miqdarı")]
    public int Quantity  { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SantekOrderId")]
    public virtual SantekOrder SantekOrder { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SantekOrderId")]
    public virtual AllProduct AllProduct { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Try adding `[InverseProperty("OrderMoneySum")] public virtual ICollection<SantekOrder> SantekOrders { get; set; }` in `OrderMoneySum`  table after `public virtual SantekOrder SantekOrder { get; set; }`, because EF assumed relationship as `SantekOrder.OrderMoneySum`.

Comment: Thanks @TetsuyaYamamoto